# cannot open dropbox.com but can ping it

Tags: networking, dropbox

So I have my computer, Windows 7 64bit OS, I can ping Dropbox.com 
[image: ping successful]

but I cannot open it in browser, I tried, Chrome, Firefox, IE, none of them works. I have the screen in Chrome as below:[image: Chrome]
I switched network provider from home to work, and switched between cable and wireless, still does not work. I have other computers and smart phones that all is able to open Dropbox.com in browser...

Access to other websites is fine, I checked my firewall and everything I can think of, and could not find any DROPBOX item in the block list.

anyone had similar experience? Is there a way to diagnose and find out the root cause of this issue?
thanks

Comment: Any Software or Searchbar installed, which could cause this?

Comment: Nope, None, as i said, i tried all different browsers, and none worked, so it is not browsers issue, i also tried behind different gateways, it must be something in the OS.

Answer (score 0):

So have You Checked Your hosts file. Be Sure dropbox is not there. if it is not

One option I always use is Disable Ethernet or Wireless Adapter and Enable it again. It resets cache , configuration and everything that most possibly went wrong.

Comment: where is the host file? i did that, i even restarted the computer but still does not work.

Comment: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc  There is a file named hosts there. Open it with Notepad. Lokk inside for www.dropbox.com . If there is a record like this. Cut the file Paste it to desktop , Cause file System won't allow you to edit it under system directory. delete that recor and paste it back. This file has local DNS mapping for OS.

Comment: nothing there related to dropbox...

Comment: have you checked your router ? Routers have outer firewall and blocking programs too. I would suggest you to reset your router as last advice

Comment: ran `tracert dropbox.com` and everything is fine:　
`Tracing route to dropbox.com [108.160.172.238]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     2 ms     2 ms     1 ms  10.61.32.1
．．．
 10    75 ms    76 ms    77 ms  www.v.dropbox.com [108.160.172.238]

Trace complete.`

Comment: I don't know mate if it is not browser , router ,firewall ,or computer than what could cause this situation . sorry I couldn't be a part of help. And particularly you can access these sites as you did pinging and trace routing but your browser can not render them. So only way left is to check Antivirus. These programmes have trusted URLs or reliabe sites tab. Just tamper with it. and don't wory you can restore default settings later.

Comment: thanks anyway, i think it must be something deep in the system!